# What does the .ros folder contain?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I hope all of you are safe and doing well
I was looking at some files which occupy a lot of storage and noticed the `.ros` folder occupies the maximum space of around 3 GBs. I believe this is some kind of cache (Please correct me if I'm wrong), I'd like to know more about it.

Is it safe to delete that folder (as it occupies a lot of space) or should I just leave it?

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380716/what-does-the-.ros-folder-contain-?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2021-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What does the .ros folder contain ?

It's the default location for all sorts of "system data", meaning log files, `rospack` caches, `rosdep` caches and a few more types of files used by some core parts of ROS (in ROS 1 at least).

`.ros` is also the default *working directory* when nodes are started using `roslaunch`, which causes quite some confusion as that would be where ROS nodes would try to read/write files specified using relative paths.

> I believe this is some kind of cache (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

most of the space will likely be taken up by log files, not the caches.

> Is it safe to delete that folder

there'd be no need to delete it. If you'd like to reduce the amount of space it occupies and don't care to retain the logs, just run `rosclean purge` and answer the prompt. See [wiki/rosclean](http://wiki.ros.org/rosclean) for some more info on that utility.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2